# C# Unity Creating Virtual Button

Tags: unity-game-engine

im trying to create a Virtual Button in Unity with the Vuforia Framework. 
I followed this Tutorial:
http://3dvrcentral.com/2016/09/19/how-to-augmented-reality-tutorials-virtual-buttons-with-unity-and-vuforia/

My Console tells me the button is pressed but as soon as I add the code to let the zombie do something my console gives me this exception. After the exception i posted my code as well.

```
  Exception in callback: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object


public class vbScipt : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler {

private GameObject vbButtonObject;
private GameObject zombie;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    vbButtonObject = GameObject.Find ("actionButton");
    zombie = GameObject.Find ("zombie");
    vbButtonObject.GetComponent<VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour> ().RegisterEventHandler (this);

}


public void OnButtonPressed (VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
    Debug.Log ("Button Pressed");
    zombie.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ();
}

public void OnButtonReleased (VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){

    Debug.Log ("Button Released");
    zombie.GetComponent<Animation> ().Stop ();

}
```

}

Comment: Is that the full exception? It should tell you what line it is occurring on - please add that part. It sounds like your script is not finding "zombie" during Start().

Comment: The comment was too long for a comment so i had to post it again in an answer. And yes you are right the error is on this line: zombie.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play (); and i don't know why. on all other tutorials it works like this

Answer (score 0):

It should be related with the line

```
zombie = GameObject.Find ("zombie");
```

Try instead using a bool and searching for the zombie after the Start() like this

```
    private bool isSetted = false;
    ...
    void Update()
    {
        if (!isSetted)
        {
            zombie = GameObject.Find("zombie");
            if (zombie != null)
                isSetted = true;
    }
    ...
```